# How do I create hamburger panels/side drawers with Xamarin.Android? (5.0+)

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm targetting Android version 5.0 with the minimal set to 4.4. I'd like to create a simple side menu with which users can select an option/page of the app.

The problem I'm facing is the number of recommended solutions for this on various blogs, forums and documentation pages. Many of them require downloading various component and additional libraries, as well as support libraries for backwards compatibility.

What method can I use if I don't need backwards compatibility and just want to make an Android application with the ugly new Material Design in mind?

Are there even built-in components for that? Or is downloading these libraries the and doing a ton of setup for them the best option I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are there even built-in components for that? Or is downloading these libraries the and doing a ton of setup for them the best option I have?

The [NavigationView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html) with `DrawerLayout` is actually the official recommended way to achieve a slidable hamburger panel. But as you said, to use it, the Material Design(Android Support Design Library) need to be installed.

If you don't want to use it. There is actually a way to implement a side drawer by directly using `Fragment`. For example:

In your activity's layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/sidedrawer"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/drawerborder">
    <Button android:id="@+id/home"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="HOME" />
    <Button android:id="@+id/settings"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="SETTINGS" />
  </LinearLayout>
  <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/container"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Code behind:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Create your application here
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.layout1);

    Button home = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.home);
    home.Click += (sender, e) =>
    {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = this.FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
        HomeFragment homefragment = new HomeFragment();
        transaction.Replace(Resource.Id.container, homefragment).Commit();
    };

    Button settings = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.settings);
    settings.Click += (sender, e) =>
    {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = this.FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
        SettingsFragment settingsfragment = new SettingsFragment();
        transaction.Replace(Resource.Id.container, settingsfragment).Commit();
    };
}
```

I didn't add gesture and animation to the `sidedrawer` to make it slidable. You can try it by yourself.

But I can't tell which way is easier, in my opinion, installing those packages will be more convenient. To use the method I mentioned above, many works need to be done by our self. For example, the slide-in/ slide-out animation, gesture recognition, even the border of the drawer. So yes, I personally think downloading these libraries is the best option.

Edit:
I forgot to say, if you want a pop up side drawer, you may try use custom dialog.

Comment: Alright, I see. I'll try experimenting with both options. Thanks!

Comment: I ended up downloading the Android Support libraries and am experimenting with that right now. I managed to create a Toolbar, but all tutorials say that I should set the icon to something along the lines of `Resource.Drawable.ic_menu`, which doesn't exist. Am I missing something, or is that a file that I have to create myself?